# Не может считывать из файла символ ; C++

Tags: c++

Например, в файле есть текст `;s`

Код

```
char ch;
m_input >> ch; // ch = s
```

читает в `ch` символ `s`, а надо, чтобы был считан `;`

Comment: вы сами понимаете свой вопрос?

Comment: Расскажите, как вы этого добились? А то вот - https://ideone.com/DWgBbC - ну никак...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много способов не считывать из потока ввода символ.
Вот некоторые из этих

```
 char ch;
 cin.ignore(); // пропускаем символ
 getchar();    // считываем сивол, не записывая
 cin >> ch;     // считываем 3 тий символ в ch
 cout << char(cin.peek()) << endl; // выводим следующий символ
```

И если вы введете, скажем `abcd`, то выводится будет символ `d`, а `сh` будет содержать символ   `c`
Так что вы просто каким то способом в коде игнорировали или ранее читали первый символ

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае вы объявляете переменную типа char она хранит всего 1-н символ. Тебе надо использовать массив или указатель на тип char  `char* ch;`